# Hibernate custom type - Could not determine a type for class

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I'm using postgres with custom type extension (visible as `Type.OTHER`), I want to be able to use the type in native queries without casting. My Java type is called `EmbVector` and my custom type is `PostgresVectorCol2Type  implements UserType`. My Postgres entity is defined like this:

```
@TypeDef(
    name = "vector",
    defaultForType = EmbVector::class,
    typeClass = PostgresVectorCol2Type::class
)
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
class EmbeddingRecord {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    var id: Long = 0

    @Column
    @Type(type = "vector")
    lateinit var embedding: EmbVector

    @Column
    lateinit var label: String
}
```

And I do konw my `@TypeDef` should be enough to let proper types be picked for `embedding` without additional `@Type` annotation. The last part of the puzzle is supposedly an implementation of Postgrest dialect:

```
public class VectorPostgreDialect extends PostgreSQL10Dialect {

    public VectorPostgreDialect() {
        //this.registerColumnType(Types.OTHER, "vector");
        registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, EmbVector.class.getName());
    }
}
```

registered in `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.config=pl.qus.maxvector.hibernate.customtypes.VectorPostgreDialect
```

Yet all this fails miserably in the end with:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not determine a type for class: pl.qus.maxvector.model.EmbVector
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.resolveParameterBindType(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1129)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.resolveParameterBindType(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1112)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.bindValue(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.setBindValue(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:501)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.setParameter(NativeQueryImpl.java:650)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:410)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.setParameter(Unknown Source)
    at pl.qus.maxvector.dao.PostgresVectorDAOImpl.selectClosest(PostgresVectorDAOImpl.kt:95)
```

The online documentation is very sparse and generally says all the above steps are enough. Am I missing something?